# Jquery select DOM elements and access inner elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to make small script. I have main div that has 300 inner divs and I access them by:

```
$("#items").find(".item").each(function(index,ele){
    console.log(ele);
})
```

So it logs me all the inner divs.
Now i want to access labels and read their inner html of these found divs.

How i can do that? Tried to mess with `ele.label` & `ele.$("label")`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Provide complete code

Comment: i dont have any other code just trying to do that script on existing page using page souce in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.find` or `.children` to find children/nested elements.

```
$(ele).children('label') // takes just direct children
$(ele).find('label') // take all nested labels
```

Comment: You need to use `$(ele).` instead of just `ele.`

Comment: yes when i try to do this it gives me: ele.find is not a function

Comment: @JanKowalski: I've updated my answer, there was a typo.

Comment: i think thats what i was looking for. Thanks for help

Comment: You forgot `.html()`

Comment: @panther

Now i want to take the .html() of label and send it to field value that is also in same .item div. How would u do that?

Comment: @JanKowalski [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/)

Answer (score 0):

Either you can do it directly with `html()` method to get innerHTML of `label`.

```
$("#items").find(".item label").each(function(index,ele){
    console.log($(ele).html())});
```

Or after loop

```
$("#items").find(".item").each(function(index,ele){
    console.log($(ele).find('label').html();)})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it helps

```js
$("#items").find(".item").each((i, e) => console.log(e.innerHTML))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about pure javascript :)

```
itemslabelArr = document.querySelectorAll("#items .item label")
for (var i = 0, len = itemslabelArr.length; i < len; i++) {
console.log(itemslabelArr[i].innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#items .item").each(function(index,element){
    var labelText = $('label', element).text(); // or .html()
    console.log(labelText);
})
```